# system of differential equations in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, differentials

[image]
How can I formulate the addressed system of differential equations in Mathematica for to find a general solution for $f[x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3]$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530498/system-of-differential-equations-in-mathematica

Comment: Please edit your question to include the question in Mathematica format.  Also, `z` is not a valid dependent variable.

Comment: I can not add more characters here, this webpage doesn't let me to add more than two lines. Because of it I made that link.

Comment: I know the solution but I can not find it by Mathematica. I am  a starter in Mathematica.

Comment: You can edit your question to add any amount of material.   I am asking that you add all your equations in Mathematica format to your question.  Pictures of your equations are not useful, because the reader cannot copy them into Mathematica and run them themselves.

Comment: I will try to do it, but how to add them in mathematica format? it comes with not beautiful format!?

Comment: You need to group your list of equations between braces `{eqn1,...}`...Not sure if that's the only problem, but it's the source of the error message.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, @MichaelE2

Comment: You need to write @user, where "user" is the username, such as bbgodfrey, to be sure the user gets notified of your response.  The author of the post is always notified of comments to his or her post.  (And you can have only one at+user in a comment.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 sorry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31608/discussion-between-farrokh-and-michael-e2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have transcribed the code from the image, and corrected the errors identified by the OP, MichaelE2 and me:

```
p = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x1];
q = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x2];
r = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x3];
o = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], y1];
x = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], y2];
a = D[f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], y3];

equ1 = 2 x1 p + 2 x2 q + 2 x3 r - y1 o - y2 x - y3 a;
equ2 = -x1 p - x2 q - x3 r + 2 y1 o + 2 y2 x + 2 y3 a;
equ3 = (x1 (x1 + 2 x2 + 2 x3)) p + (x2 (x2 + 2 x3)) q + (x3^2) r 
    - (y1 (x2 + x3)) o - y2 x3 x;
equ4 = (y1 (y1 + 2 y2 + 2 y3)) o + (y2 (y2 + 2 y3)) x + (y3^2) a 
    - (x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)) p - x2 (y2 +  y3) q - x3 y3 r;
DSolve[{equ1 == 0, equ2 == 0, equ3 == 0, equ4 == 0}, f, {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}]
```

`DSolve` returns un-evaluated, meaning that it can not solve the system of equations.

**Addendum**

Nonetheless, with `equ4` now corrected by the OP, some progress can be made.

```
DSolve[2 equ1 + equ2 == 0, f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}][[1, 1]]
(* f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3] -> C[1][x2/x1, x3/x1, y1, y2, y3] *)
DSolve[equ1 + 2 equ2 == 0, f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], {x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}][[1, 1]]
(* f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3] -> C[1][x1, x2, x3, y2/y1, y3/y1] *)
```

Consequently, the dimensionality of this problem can be reduced from six to four.

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_, y3_] := g[x2/x1, x3/x1, y2/y1, y3/y1]
equ5 = FullSimplify[(equ3/x1) /. {x2 -> v2 x1, x3 -> v3 x1, y2 -> w2 y1, y3 -> w3 y1}]
(*       (v2 + v3)*w3*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] + 
                v2*w2*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] - 
   v3*(1 + 2*v2 + v3)*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] - 
          v2*(1 + v2)*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] *)
equ6 = FullSimplify[(equ4/y1) /. {x2 -> v2 x1, x3 -> v3 x1, y2 -> w2 y1, y3 -> w3 y1}]
(* -(w3*(1 + 2*w2 + w3)*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3]) - 
            w2*(1 + w2)*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] + 
            v3*(1 + w2)*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] + 
                     v2*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] *)
```

Although `DSolve` cannot solve these equations as a pair either, it can solve each separately.

```
DSolve[equ5 == 0, g[v2, v3, w2, w3], {v2, v3, w2, w3}][[1, 1]]/.C[1] -> c5
(* g[v2, v3, w2, w3] -> c5[(v2 (1 + v2 + v3))/v3, (1 + v2) w2, (v3 w3)/v2] *)
(DSolve[equ6 == 0, g[v2, v3, w2, w3], {v2, v3, w2, w3}][[1, 1]] /. 
    C[1] -> c6) // FullSimplify
(* g[v2, v3, w2, w3] -> c6[-((v3 (1 + w2))/v2), ((1 + w2) (1 + w2 + w3))/(v2 w3), 
   -Log[(1 + w2)/(v2 w2)]] *)
```

The first results indicates that `g` is a function of

```
var5 = List @@ %%[[2]]
(* {(v2 (1 + v2 + v3))/v3, (1 + v2) w2, (v3 w3)/v2} *)
```

and also

```
var6 = List @@ %%[[2]]
(* {-((v3 (1 + w2))/v2), ((1 + w2) (1 + w2 + w3))/(v2 w3), -Log[(1 + w2)/(v2 w2)]} *)
```

The second list of functions can be simplified by

```
var6[[3]] = Exp[var6[[3]]]; 
var6[[1]] = -var6[[1]] var6[[3]]; 
var6[[2]] = var6[[2]] var6[[3]]; 
var6
(* {v3 w2, (w2 (1 + w2 + w3))/w3, (v2 w2)/(1 + w2)} *)
```

The next step is to combine the two expressions for `g` to obtain a single expression, presumably as a function of two variables.  I do not have time now to pursue this further and invite others to do so.

**Completed Solution**

The system of PDEs above can be solved using the procedure described in Chapter V, Sec IV of [Goursat's Differential Equations](https://archive.org/details/differentialequa028961mbp).  The first step is to find the complete, non-commutative group of differential operators that includes `equ5` and `equ6`.

```
comm[equa_, equb_] :=
    Collect[(equa /. {Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equb, v2], 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equb, v3], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equb, w2], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equb, w3]}) - 
    (equb /. {Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equa, v2], 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equa, v3], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equa, w2], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] -> D[equa, w3]}), 
    {Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3], Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3], Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3]}, 
    Simplify]
equ7 = comm[equ5, equ6]
(* -(w3*(v3*(1 + w2 + w3) + v2*(1 + 2*w2 + w3))*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][v2, v3, w2, w3])
- v2*w2*(1 + w2)*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] + v3*(v3*(1 + w2) 
+ v2*(2 + w2))*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] + 
v2^2*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][g][v2, v3, w2, w3] *)
```

which by inspection is independent of `equ5` and `equ6`.  On the other hand, `comm[equ5, equ7]` and `comm[equ6, equ7]` do not yield independent equations, again by inspection.  Thus `{equ5, equ6, equ7}` is a complete group of three operators in four independent variables.  From this information alone, we know that `g` is an arbitrary function of precisely one first integral.  This first integral can be obtained by systematically eliminating variables and equations, one pair at a time, until a single equation of two variable remains.  Start by solving any one of the equations.

```
DSolve[equ5 == 0, g[v2, v3, w2, w3], {v2, v3, w2, w3}][[1, 1]]
(* g[v2, v3, w2, w3] -> C[1][(v2 (1 + v2 + v3))/v3, (1 + v2) w2, (v3 w3)/v2] *)
```

and use the solution as the basis for a change of variables

```
g[v2_, v3_, w2_, w3_] := h[w2, (v2 (1 + v2 + v3))/v3, (1 + v2) w2, (v3 w3)/v2]
solw2 = equ5/(v2 w2) // Simplify
(* Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][h][w2, (v2*(1 + v2 + v3))/v3, (1 + v2)*w2, (v3*w3)/v2] *)
```

indicating that `h` is independent of `w2`.  This leaves us with two equations in three variables

```
newvar = Solve[Thread[{b1, b2, b3, b4} == List @@ solw2], {v2, v3, w2, w3}] // Flatten;
(((b3 equ7/(b1 - b3)) // FullSimplify) /. solw2 -> 0 /. newvar) // FullSimplify;
Collect[((equ6 // FullSimplify) /. solw2 -> 0 /. newvar) // 
    FullSimplify, b1, FullSimplify] + % b1/b3
equ10 = %% /. Derivative[0, n1_, n2_, n3_][h][b1, b2, b3, b4] -> 
    Derivative[n1, n2, n3][h][b2, b3, b4]
(* b4*(b3 + b4 + b2*b4)*Derivative[0, 0, 1][h][b2, b3, b4] + (1 + b3)*
(b3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][h][b2, b3, b4] + (1 + b2)*Derivative[1, 0, 0][h][b2, b3, b4]) *)
equ11 = %% /. Derivative[0, n1_, n2_, n3_][h][b1, b2, b3, b4] -> 
    Derivative[n1, n2, n3][h][b2, b3, b4]
(* (-1 + b4)*b4*Derivative[0, 0, 1][h][b2, b3, b4] + (1 + b2 + b3)
*Derivative[1, 0, 0][h][b2, b3, b4] *)
```

Proceeding as before , we next solve one of `equ10` and `equ11`.  (Choose the simpler one.)

```
DSolve[equ11 == 0, h[b2, b3, b4], {b2, b3, b4}][[1, 1, 2]]
(* h[b2, b3, b4] -> C[1][b3][Log[(1 - b4)/((1 + b2 + b3) b4)] *)
```

and use it as the basis for a further change of variables.

```
h[b2_, b3_, b4_] := k[b2, b3, (1 - b4)/((1 + b2 + b3) b4)]
solb2 = (equ11/(1 + b2 + b3)) // Simplify
(* Derivative[1, 0, 0][k][b2, b3, (1 - b4)/(b4 + b2*b4 + b3*b4)] *)
```

indicating that `k` is independent of `b2`.  This leaves us with one equation in two variables.

```
newvar1 = Solve[Thread[{c2, c3, c4} == List @@ solb2], {b2, b3, b4}] // Flatten;
((equ10 // FullSimplify) /. solb2 -> 0 /. newvar1) // FullSimplify
equ12 = % /. Derivative[0, n1_, n2_][k][c2, c3, c4] -> Derivative[n1, n2][k][c3, c4]
(* -((1 + c4 + 2*c3*c4)*Derivative[0, 1][k][c3, c4]) + c3*(1 + c3)
*Derivative[1, 0][k][c3, c4] *)
```

Finally, `DSolve` yields

```
DSolve[equ12 == 0, k[c3, c4], {c3, c4}][[1, 1, 2]]
(* k[c3, c4] -> C[1][c3 (1 + c4 + c3 c4)] *)
```

Transforming back to the original independent variables gives

```
(((% /. Thread[{c2, c3, c4} -> List @@ solb2]) // Simplify) /. 
    Thread[{b1, b2, b3, b4} -> List @@ solw2]) // Simplify
(* C[1][(v2 w2 (1 + (1 + v2) w2 + (1 + v2 + v3) w3))/((v2 + v3 + v3 w2) w3)] *)
```

Because so much algebra has been required, it seems prudent to verify the answer.

```
g[v2_, v3_, w2_, w3_] := %
{equ5, equ6, equ7} // Simplify
(* {0, 0, 0} *)
```

Finally, designating the solution for `g` as `ansg`,

```
(ansg /. {v2 -> x2/x1, v3 -> x3/x1, w2 -> y2/y1, w3 -> y3/y1}) // Simplify
(* C[1][(x2 y2 (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)))/(x1 (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) y3)] *)
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_, y3_] := %
{equ1, equ2, equ3, equ4}
(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Thus `f` is an arbitrary function of a single first integral, as predicted.  See also the related question, [102198](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102198/1063).

Comment: Thanks you very much! but it doesn't work                                                                            https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gJkeoy6DaROHNhR25Zb2ViMkU/view?usp=sharing  @bbgodfrey

Comment: Thank you very much! but please look at the codes! It is not the solution which I want

Comment: @farrokh I strongly suggest that you stop vaguely objecting that "it doesn't work" and read the documentation so that you can set up the calculation properly by yourself.

Comment: It's exactly what I wrote and when it's not the solution which I want! I will say "it doesn't work!" It's not the solution.

Comment: @farrokh  What is the solution?

Comment: @bbgodfrey If you look at the file which I attached alraedy, you will see that this object     $\frac{(   y_3 y_2  x_1  x_3 +  y_3 y_1 x_1  x_2  +  y_3 y_1 x_1  x_3)}{(    
   y_2 y_1   x_1 x_2 +  y_2 y_2  x_1  x_2 +   y_2 y_2  x_2   x_2  +   
    y_3 y_1   x_1 x_3 +   y_3 y_2  x_1 x_3 +  y_3 y_2  x_2 x_3 +   
    y_3 y_1    x_1 x_2 +    y_3 y_2   x_1 x_2 +   y_3 y_2 x_2 x_2)}$ satisfies in all the equations (there I checked on of them). I don't know how? but I need to find $f[x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3]$ exactly as what I wrote here. Thanks!

Comment: @farrokh it seems to me that this expression, `z[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_, y3_] := (x1 (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) y3)/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)))`, satisfies `equ1 == 0` and `equ2 == 0`, but not `equ3 == 0` or `equ4 == 0`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. but I checked.   $\frac{y_3 x_1 (y_2 x_3 + y_1 x_2 + y_1 x_3)}{(y_2 x_2 + y_3 x_3 + y_3 x_2)(y_1 x_1 + y_2 x_1 + y_2 x_2)}$ is the only nontrivial solution for this system. And satisfies in all the equations.

Comment: @farrokh it is possible for the given expression to satisfy `equ3 == 0` and `equ4 == 0`, but only subject to additional (nontrivial) conditions on the parameters that `DSolve` is not automatically aware of. `Reduce` can provide these.

Comment: @OleksandrR. you mean instead of "DSolve" I should use "Reduce"?

Comment: @farrokh I mean that `DSolve` does not produce an answer because your system of equations as you pose it does not admit a general solution. You should also specify any relations between the `{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}` that you know about, and maybe you will have better luck with `DSolve`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I did it. But I think it also didn't work or probably I couldn't use it!

Comment: @OleksandrR. but I work on a classical space (not quantum space) and the variables can commute with each other and there is no additional relation between them.

Comment: @farrokh the commutation relation is rather important! It should be specified. If you need help with this, please rephrase your question (or delete and replace it) to specify (with copyable code, not images or downloads) a totally correct input, the desired output, and the fact that the variables commute.

Comment: @OleksandrR let me add the relation to see what will happen. I will manage the entire of the question. Thanks!

Comment: @OleksandrR. I don't know how to add commutation relation in mathematica for my variables. can you help me?

Comment: @farrokh I don't know how to do it either, actually. I tried several approaches and did not have success with any of them. This will make a good question, if you can pose it clearly and directly enough. On this question, it has taken quite some comments to discover the real problem, but I think that now you are in a position to write a new, better question. One further point that was not clear: do *all* the variables commute, or only the `x`s with the `x`s and the `y`s with the `y`s? Include this information in your new question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thank you very much for your time and help. yes, it's a very interesting question. Yes, I will do it. On Tuesday I will visit my Professor and maybe we will be able to solve it, hopefully.

Comment: @farrokh  With respect to your comment above, any expression of the form `z[x2/x1, x3/x1, y2/y1, y3/y1]` satisfies the first two equations.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, it is true. Because the first two equations are the degree equations. And they show that just functions with degree zero can be a candidate for the main solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, there was a miss calculating. Thank you very much for to point it out. The correct equation is this one "equ4 = (y1 (y1 + 2 y2 + 2 y3)) o + (y2 (y2 + 2 y3)) x + (y3^2) a 
    - (x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)) p -  (y2 +  y3) q - x3 y3 r"

Comment: @bbgodfrey but it is an a same order with "equ3" and I put it there this morning    " IN[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_,  y3_] := ( y3 x1 (y2 x3 + y1 x2 + y1 x3))/(( y2 x2 + y3 x3 + y3 x2  ) (y1 x1 + y2 x1 + y2 x2))
EIN[x1_, x2_, x3_, y1_, y2_,  y3_] := (y1 (y1 + 2 y2 + 2 y3))  D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3],    y1] + (y2 (y2 + 2 y3)) D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3],  y2] + (y3)^2 D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], y3]  - (x1 (y1 + y2 + y3))  D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x1] -  x2 (y2 + y3) D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x2] -  x3 y3 D[IN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3], x3] "

Comment: GHxp := EIN[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3] // Simplify

Comment: GHxp // Simplify

Comment: @bbgodfrey please put these codes on your note then you will see that it will give us zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31649/discussion-between-farrokh-and-bbgodfrey).

Comment: @bbgodfrey No, the current equations are showing that our " f " (which we supposed is our answer) is satisfying in the corrected "equ4" which I put it in your answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry, yes you are right. I made mistake there. I corrected and  added some statement about the relation between the variables.